# Context menu entry not appearing for .cshtml files in code editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have created [a Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MSXrules.BrowseinremoteGitrepository) that adds two entries to the context menu that appears when right clicking on two places: an item in solution explorer, and anywhere in an open code editor window.

The problem that I am facing is that the menu entries do not appear when clicking in the code editor window **if** the file being edited is a `.cshtml` file (it does appear when clicking in solution explorer, though). With any other file type that I have tested it works just fine.

Here's how I define the menu entries in the `.vsct` file:

```
<Groups>
  <Group guid="guidBrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandPackageCmdSet" 
         id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>
  </Group>
  <Group guid="guidBrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandPackageCmdSet" 
         id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN"/>
  </Group>
</Groups>

<Buttons>
    <Button guid="guidBrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandPackageCmdSet" 
            id="BrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidBrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPicGit" />
    <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Browse in remote repository</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>

  <Button guid="guidBrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandPackageCmdSet"
          id="CopyRemoteGitRepoUrlCommandId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
  <Parent guid="guidBrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
  <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPicGit" />
  <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
  <Strings>
    <ButtonText>Copy URL of remote repository version</ButtonText>
  </Strings>
  </Button>
</Buttons>
```

The menu entries are created as instances of `OleMenuCommand` within the command constructor:

```
var commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) 
    as OleMenuCommandService;
if (commandService == null) return;

var browseMenuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, BrowseCommandId);
var browseMenuItem = new OleMenuCommand(BrowseMenuItemCallback, browseMenuCommandID);
browseMenuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += MenuItemOnBeforeQueryStatus;
commandService.AddCommand(browseMenuItem);
//same for the other entry
```

`MenuItemOnBeforeQueryStatus` set `sender`'s `Visible` and `Enabled` to true or false as appropriate.

So, what am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

For completeness, here are the changes that I needed to do in the `.vsct` file to implement [the change suggested by Carlos Quintero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41571665/4574):

1) Added the following inside `<Symbols>`:

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidCshtmlCodeEditor" value="{78F03954-2FB8-4087-8CE7-59D71710B3BB}" />
```

2) Added the following inside `<Groups>`:

```
<Group guid="guidBrowseInRemoteGitRepoCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidCshtmlCodeEditor" id="IDM_VS_TOOL_STANDARD"/>
</Group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from Ed. Dore (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c5eb211-3985-426c-a3a2-9da4473dbaf4/my-context-menu-item-made-by-menu-command-in-visual-studio-package-is-not-shown-in-cshtml-files?forum=vsx):

There's a different context menu being displayed for .cshtml files.

If you use the EnableVSIPLogging registry value, (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\General), as described by this old article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

You'll see there are two different context menus in use.

.CS files use:

```
Guid = {D309F791-903F-11D0-9EFC-00A0C911004F}
GuidID = 4
CmdID = 1037
Type = 0x00000400
Flags = 0x00000000
NameLoc = Code Window
```

and .CSHTML files use:

```
Guid = {78F03954-2FB8-4087-8CE7-59D71710B3BB}
GuidID = 395
CmdID = 1
Type = 0x00000400
Flags = 0x00000000
NameLoc = HTML Context
```

So you need to modify your .vsct file accordingly.